# No index URL separator symbol via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, symbols

I have a WordPress website with the basic structure: the URL keyword separator symbols are /. The problem is that the pages I create can be accessed using the / or + symbols in the URL.

I mean, I can access the same page in mydomain.com/example-page/ and mydomain.com/example+page/. I know that this is harmful for SEO so I make a question: is it possible to set, via htaccess, a noindex nofollow order to all the pages that uses the + symbol separator in the URL?

If you have a better solution, I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use (before your actual htaccess code):

```
RewriteEngine on
# executes repeatedly as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s.*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE]
# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Who redirects version example+page to example-page